# Click on an element: copy its text to an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I searching a method to copy text to an input field, text can be in some  tag or  - it doesn't matter, but after clicking on this value I need to put this to input field (type text). I think it is possible with JavaScript/jQuery, but I don't know how to write script like this.

Comment: Let us know what you've already tried, some code examples, etc.

Comment: make click event for the text and define the method using jquery.

Comment: For example I have something like this:
 `<input type="text" name="inp"/>
<a href="">text copy1</a> <a href="">other text</a>`
And when I click on <a..text copy1..> I want to put "text copy1" in my input field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just look at this example

**HTML PART**

```
<div class="copy">Copy me</div>
<span class="copy">Hey copy me</span>
<a href="#" class="copy">Me too</a>

<input type="text" class="paste" value="" />
```

**JQuery PART**

```
$(document).on('click', '.copy', function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); 
   $('.paste').val($(this).text());
});
```

[**SEE IN ACTION**](http://jsfiddle.net/kn4umkys/)

Answer (score 0):

Give unique id to your input text

for example

and in OnClick event function write following line of code

$("#1").val('some text');

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am not clear about question. Anyway please find below working Fiddle,

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/8GS7b/27/)

```
<input type="text" id="txt_name" placeholder="Enter text to copy"/>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="txt_name_copy" placeholder="Copied Text Here..."/>

<input type="button" id="btn_Run" onclick="fn_copy();" value="Copy Text"/>
```

Function here :

```
function fn_copy()
{
var temp = document.getElementById("txt_name").value;
if(temp != "")
{
   document.getElementById("txt_name_copy").value = temp;
}
else
alert("Text is Empty");
}
```